# Clicking a button to change visibility

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to set the visibility to false when a button is clicked, but the compiler says "incompatible types". The error occurs where it says `if (frame.setVisible(true))` I used `JFrame`, `JButton`, `JLabel`, `BorderLayout`, `ActionEvent`, and `ActionListener`

```
Object source = event.getSource();

        if (source == changeTextButton)
        {
            if (label.getText().equals(LABEL1))
            {
                label.setText(LABEL2);
            }
            else
            {
                label.setText(LABEL1);
            }
        }  // end of if (source == button)

        if (source == closeButton)
        {
            if (frame.setVisible(true))
            {
                setVisible(false);
            }
        } // end of if (source == closeButton)
```

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: "if (frame.setVisible(true))"

Comment: And again, the problem is that this statement is not valid Java. You're in effect stating `if (void)` which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4):

`frame.setVisible(true)` does not return a boolean result, and so cannot be placed inside the test portion of an if block. Please look at the API and you'll see that it is declared as returning `void` -- nothing -- and so do not put inside that if boolean check.

To restate, per the Java API, the `setVisible` method signature looks like:

```
// Window class
public void setVisible(boolean visible)
```

So again, the method is declared as returning void, and so your code is equivalent to doing:

```
if (void) {
  // do something
}
```

Which does not make sense to the compiler since void is neither true nor false.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to use is instead:

```
if(frame.isVisible()){
fram.setVisible(False);
}

frame.isVisible() returns a boolean (true or false)
```

You might not even need the `if statement` and just always do `frame.setVisible(false)` when `closeButton` is pressed.